# Pandas/Python add a row based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

```
 YY_MM_CD customerid pol_no    type   WE   WP 
2019-07   15680      1313145    new    3     89     
2020-01   14672      1418080    renwd  -8    223     
2019-01   15681      1213143    new    4      8      
2019-01   15683      1213344    new    -6     3
2019-03   14678      1418280    renwd  -66    -7
```

Now . I have some x years of data and i am taking for snapshot of 19-20. Suppose if a customer in this snapshot paid premium on 01/11/2019 the customer didn't paid premium on 01/11/2020 so that record will be not their in data. I need to created a dummy record for that customer . Like this customer id 15681 and keep their WE and WP as 0 0 since customer didn't paid

```
YY_MM_CD customerid pol_no    type    WE     WP
2019-07  15680      1313145    new     3     89
2020-01  14672      1418080    renwd  -8    223
2019-01  15681      1213143    new     4      8
2020-01  15681      1213143    new     0      0
2019-03  14678      1418280    renwd  -66    -7
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't create a dummy datapoint. Write the expiration date next to each customer id. Then when accessing the data just check if the current data is before the expiration date.

Simpler and cleaner

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to do what you asked (add a row or column based on a condition):

1. You need to group the customers
2. Use a lambda function to add your condition

For example.

```
    new_df = pd.DataFrame()
    df = YOURDATA
    groups = df.groupby("customerid")
    for group in groups: 
        if len(group) < 2: #your condition
           df2 = pd.DataFrame( ADD YOUR DATA HERE)
           new_df.append(df2, ignore_index=True)
```

at the end you can combine new_df and df with concat:https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html